# Can't find the Pspice model for a diode

Tags: diodes, simulation, spice, pspice, model

Last time I had an issue I posted a question and the answer was pretty useful, so it's the time to try to find the answer to a new one.

I don't seem to be able to find the Pspice model for the following diode: DSA120C150QB. I have searched in the two manufacturers page and also tried to make total shots in the dark trying to find what I need, but I haven't found anything useful, just the datasheet.

I was wondering if someone with more experience could tell me how to find the model for the diode or if some of them just can't be found, or maybe drop the url x) if it's not much work.

Comment: What evidence do you have that a model exists?

Comment: You can make your own model from a [datasheet](https://ixapps.ixys.com/datasheet/dsa120c150qb.pdf) chart. I've done that a number of times before. Would that be adequate for your use?

Comment: Looks like the bulk impedance is under \$R_{_\text{S}}=3\:\text{m}\Omega\$. The rest is just working out the saturation current and the non-ideality factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I was wondering if someone with more experience could tell me how to
> find the model for the diode or if some of them just can't be found*

[image]

Spice models for dual diodes are much, much rarer than for single diodes so, speak to the supplier (IXYS) and ask them what the equivalent device is for each diode inside the dual version.

Then you might have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any sim with an ideal Sch. Diode with Rs=3.9 mΩ and add 2000 pF @ 0V varicap load. Even Falstad's can model this with Saturation current levels , series Rs and emission coefficient.